# BlackJack program freezes after starting the game

Tags: c#, freeze, blackjack

I'm creating a BlackJack game in C#, everything (I'm pretty sure) works, before it gets to my Do-While loop(where everything in the actual game happens.) and when it does, it just either freezes or nothing happens at all. I noticed when I get rid of my Do-While loop the game doesn't freeze, so I'm guessing it's in an infinite loop or something, but I'm not sure what to do here.

```
namespace Blackjack
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Boolean standClicked = false;
        public Boolean hitClicked = false;
        public Boolean over;
        public Cards[] cardSet = new Cards[5];
        public PictureBox[] picArray = new PictureBox[5];
        public int points;
        public int i;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //Makes all card images hidden 
            Card1.Hide();
            Card2.Hide();
            Card3.Hide();
            Card4.Hide();
            Card5.Hide();

            //Makes the win-lose label blank
            winOrLoseLabel.Text = " ";

            buttonHit.Hide();
            buttonStand.Hide();


        }


        private void buttonExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Closes the application
            this.Close();
        }

        private Image SetImage(int cardValue)
        {

            Image _ = null;

            if (cardValue >= 0)
            {
                for (int check = 0; check >= 50; check++)
                {

                    if (cardValue == check)
                    {
                        _ = imageList1.Images[check];
                    }

                }

            }

            if (_ == null)
            {
                _ = imageList1.Images[0];
            }
            return _;

        }

        public void buttonHit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hitClicked = true;

            if (hitClicked == true)
            {

                picArray[i].Image = SetImage(cardSet[i].GetValue());
                points += cardSet[i].CardValue();
                pointCounter.Text = points.ToString();

            }

            points += Convert.ToInt32(pointCounter.Text);
            if (points >= 21)
                over = true;
            else
                over = false;

            i++;

        }

        private void buttonStand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            standClicked = true;
            buttonHit.Enabled = false;
        }



        private void buttonPlay_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Reveals all cards on the form
            Card1.Show();
            Card2.Show();
            Card3.Show();
            Card4.Show();
            Card5.Show();

            //Hides the logo as well as the play and exit buttons
            pictureBox3.Hide();
            buttonPlay.Hide();
            buttonExit.Hide();

            //Sets both hit and stand buttons to be enabled again
            buttonHit.Show();
            buttonStand.Show();
            buttonHit.Enabled = true;
            buttonStand.Enabled = true;


            //Makes the win-lose label blank
            winOrLoseLabel.Text = " ";


            //Sets the "standClicked boolean value to false - to not automatically end the game
            pointCounter.Text = "0";
            points = Convert.ToInt32(pointCounter.Text);

            //Makes the cardset values randomized
            cardSet[0] = new Cards(0);
            cardSet[0].Value = 0;
            cardSet[0].SetCards();

            cardSet[1] = new Cards(0);
            cardSet[1].Value = 0;
            cardSet[1].SetCards();

            cardSet[2] = new Cards(0);
            cardSet[2].Value = 0;
            cardSet[2].SetCards();

            cardSet[3] = new Cards(0);
            cardSet[3].Value = 0;
            cardSet[3].SetCards();

            cardSet[4] = new Cards(0);
            cardSet[4].Value = 0;
            cardSet[4].SetCards();



            // PictureBox array to allow changes to different PictureBoxes
            PictureBox[] picArray = new PictureBox[5];

            // Card thing
            for (int x = 0; x > picArray.Length; x++)
            {
                picArray[x] = new PictureBox();
            }

            picArray[0] = Card1;
            picArray[1] = Card2;
            picArray[2] = Card3;
            picArray[3] = Card4;
            picArray[4] = Card5;


            // Will automatically show you your first card, while the rest will stay hidden until you press the Hit button.
            picArray[0].Image = SetImage(cardSet[0].GetValue());
            points += cardSet[0].CardValue();
            pointCounter.Text = points.ToString();
            i = 1;

            //Sets over boolean to false - to not automatically end the game
            over = false;
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void pictureBox7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

     private void Card2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void pictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void buttonPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void buttonPlay_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And my Card Class if you need it as well

```
using System;

public class Cards
{


    Random rand = new Random();
    public int Value = 0;




    public Cards(int value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public int GetValue()
    {
        return Value;
    }

    public int CardValue()
    {
        if (Value == 0 || Value == 1 || Value == 2 || Value == 3)
            return 2;
        else if (Value == 4 || Value == 5 || Value == 6 || Value == 7)
            return 3;
        else if (Value == 8 || Value == 9 || Value == 10 || Value == 11)
            return 4;
        else if (Value == 12 || Value == 13 || Value == 14 || Value == 15)
            return 5;
        else if (Value == 16 || Value == 17 || Value == 18 || Value == 19)
            return 6;
        else if (Value == 20 || Value == 21 || Value == 22 || Value == 23)
            return 7;
        else if (Value == 24 || Value == 25 || Value == 26 || Value == 27)
            return 8;
        else if (Value == 28 || Value == 29 || Value == 30 || Value == 31)
            return 9;
        else if (Value == 32 || Value == 33 || Value == 34 || Value == 35)
            return 10;
        else if (Value == 36 || Value == 37 || Value == 38 || Value == 39)
            return 1;
        else if (Value == 40 || Value == 41 || Value == 42 || Value == 43 || Value == 44 || Value == 45 || Value == 46 || Value == 47)
            return 10;

        else
            return 2;
    }


    public void SetCards()
    {
        //Adds a random value to card
        int ranumber = rand.Next(0, 47);
        Value = ranumber;
    }


}
```

I'm still sort of new at programming, and this is my first real project. Any help on how I can make my code better and or fix the problem would mean a million to me.

Comment: You have an endless loop in `buttonPlay_Click_1` there will be no way for any button click to register.  While Blackjack is often played with multiple decks so that there more than 1 of each Rank+Suit, you are picking cards randomly so there could be 30 Kings or whatever.  You ought to create 1 or more decks and *shuffle* them to simply use them in a random order

Comment: @holypetralich You should just use the `click` `event handlers` of the buttons. Handle the action of clicking a specific button and show a card or perform some other action in the button's `event handler`.

Comment: @Ryan Wilson May I ask what this means? I'm sorry - I'm still kinda new to this, I'd like to make sure I understand what I'm told here.

Comment: @Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp Where's the endless loop? I'm not sure where or how I should fix it, i'm sorry.

Comment: @HolyPetRalich `public void buttonHit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` and `private void buttonStand_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` - These methods are called on the click event of each respective button. You already seem to understand this as you are setting boolean values inside of those methods. Instead of setting booleans, perform your logic there instead of trying to do it in the loop and get rid of the loop altogether.

Comment: Just hit Ctrl-Break when it "freezes" and it will show you the endless loop (the `do...while` loop

Comment: @Ryan Wilson Okay, I think I understand what you said and tried that out. But when I move the "`if (hitClicked == true)
            {

                picArray[i].Image = SetImage(cardSet[i].GetValue());
                points += cardSet[i].CardValue();
                points += Convert.ToInt32(pointCounter.Text);
            }`" Both picArray and cardSet get syntax errors, I've tried to fix it but I'm not sure how to. I'm probably getting real dumb here, excuse me.

Comment: @HolyPetRalich `picArray` and `cardSet` are currently local to the method they are contained in, move them to the global scope of the class -> ie. up where you declared `standClicked` and `hitClicked` `Booleans`

Comment: @Ryan Wilson So I've put these variable to be global:  `public Boolean standClicked = false;
        public Boolean hitClicked = false;
        public Boolean over;
        public Cards[] cardSet = new Cards[5];
        public PictureBox[] picArray = new PictureBox[5];
        public int points;
        public int i;` But I'm not sure what I should do with the rest of the loop: Like the checker for if the points are over 21

Comment: @HolyPetRalich Add that logic inside the Hit button click event method, once the card is flipped over, check if the total is over 21 and do what you need before exiting the Hit Button click event method. Remove the LOOP

Comment: @Ryan Wilson Ok, first of all, thank you so much, this means so much that you're helping me right now! I really appreciate it. I have i think one last problem here. When I press hit, at `picArray[i].Image = SetImage(cardSet[i].GetValue());` it's telling me "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object." What should I do here?

Comment: @HolyPetRalich It means something is `null` at that point. More than likely, `cardSet[i]` or `picArray[i]`. Did you initialize the arrays to anything before that line of code? If you can edit your post to include your updated code, it would be helpful to me for finding the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210024/discussion-between-holypetralich-and-ryan-wilson).